# Azure WebJob deployment keeps failing

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-webjobs, msdeploy, webjob

Since yesterday I'm suddenly having consistent deployment failures for my existing WebJobs. The error I'm getting is

```
Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://octotrip-api-test-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=octotrip-api-test__dev ...
Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
Adding directory (XXX\app_data).
Adding directory (XXX\app_data\jobs).
Adding directory (XXX\app_data\jobs\continuous).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4295,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. ((3/16/2017 1:32:23 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

(3/16/2017 1:32:23 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create Directory' on 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous'.
The error code was 0x800700B7.
Cannot create "D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous" because a file or directory with the same name already exists.
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirectoryEx.CreateDirectory(String path)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, DeploymentObject source)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
Publish failed to deploy.
```

Important to note that at the time of the deployment; there is no app_data folder (I removed it manually using FTP). You can see it is creating the folder structure step by step; app_data, then the jobs folder, then the continuous folder. I confirmed using FTP that he succesfully creates the app_data/jobs folder; but creating the continuous folder consistently crashes.

This happens when deploying using a build definition in VSTS as well as deploying as a WebJob from within Visual Studio; with all the WebJob NuGet up to date.

Thanks

Comment: Try logon to SCM Kudu console (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) and manually create the same folder - see if the same issue.  This is to isolate whether file system or VSTS publishing issue.

Comment: Hi @SuwatCh , thank you for your quick reply. I'm encountering the same issue when trying to create the folder using the Kudu debug console.
rmdir app_data (success)
mkdir app_data (success)
mkdir app_data/jobs (success)
mkdir app_data/jobs/continuous (fail - subdir or file continuous already exists)

Comment: We can see the same issue on your site.  We will investigate.   Will update.

Comment: mind trying restart the site and see if it helps.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4496#issuecomment-309294640

There's an issue with webjobs not stopping, and therefore not deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very odd that can't create  folder for WebJob. I can't repro it in my side. Do you have a try to deploy it to another website to check whether it can be repro?
Based on my experience,  we could troubleshoot with following ways:

1. Restart the Website
2. If it is possible try to redeploy the Website and  remove additional files at destination

[image]

3. Scale up and scale down back Service plan

> **Note**:change will be applied to all WebApps in the ServicePlan

4. Please contact  Azure Support team for help if it is not resolved .

Comment: 1) Didnt help
2) Tried, didnt help
3) Not tested yet; but I think it might work.

Right now I solved it by just creating a new App Service. I think it's simply a corrupted file system or something

Comment: I posted more information + a screenshot in my answer. Thanks for reaching out though !!!

Comment: Scaling up and down actually fixed the issue too.

Answer (score 1):

Worked around the issue by simply creating a new Azure Web App. Something messed up going on with the file system. Take a look.

app_data or subdirectories of app_data don't exist on the server. (confirmed using CMD and FTP).

This only happens for 
app_data\jobs\triggered and
app_data\jobs\continuous

(app_data\jobs\triggereddddd works for example)

These folders have existed on this server before (they contain the data for the WebJobs that we're running)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. open Azure Portal and go to your web app
2. Under "development tools" select "K Advanced Tools" this will open the Kudu control panel in a new browser window.
3. Select "Debug Console" -> "CMD"
   [image]
4. in the Items table, locate the wwwroot entry and delete it.
5. continue working ...